# Issues with more than one "&" condition inside if statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm doing an IF statement in R to create a variable in R.

I'm having an error that I can't detect to what it refers exactly so I can't fix it. Can somebody help me?

```
library(install.load)
install_load("checkmate", "expss")

amostra$escol <- NA
educd003 <- data.frame("d003" = 1:9, "codeduc" = c(1,1,3,3,5,5,7,9,9))
educd0091 <- data.frame("d009" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                        "codeduc" = c(2,2,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,8,10,10))
educd0092 <- data.frame("d009" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                        "codeduc" = c(1,1,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,7,9,9))

for (i in 1:nrow(amostra)) {
if (is.na(amostra$d001[i]) == TRUE) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- 99
} else if (amostra$d001[i] == 2) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- 0
} else if (amostra$d002[i] == 1) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- vlookup(amostra$d003[i], educd003, result_column = 2, lookup_column = 1)
} else if (amostra$d002[i] == 2 & amostra$d008[i] == 2) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- 2
} else if (amostra$d002[i] == 2 & amostra$d008[i] == 1 & amostra$d014[i] == 1) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- vlookup(amostra$d009[i], educd0091, result_column = 2, lookup_column = 1)
} else if (amostra$d002[i] == 2 & amostra$d008[i] == 1 & amostra$d014[i] == 2) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- vlookup(amostra$d009[i], educd0092, result_column = 2, lookup_column = 1)
} else if (amostra$d002[i] == 2 & amostra$d008[i] == 1 & is.na(amostra$d014[i]) == TRUE) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- vlookup(amostra$d009[i], educd0092, result_column = 2, lookup_column = 1)
} else {
  amostra$escol[i] <- NA
}
}
```

Error:

```
Error in if (amostra$d002[i] == 2 & amostra$d008[i] == 1 & amostra$d014[i] ==  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Thanks,
Wagner

Comment: Not sure this example is complete. Here `amostra` doesn't have a column named `d002` so `amostra$d002` will return NULL. I don't think this has anything to do with `&` really.

Comment: Try `&&` instead of `&` between the statements. That should help.

Comment: You might find using `all()` to be simpler than chaining multiple `&`

Comment: It is not an error but in `if (is.na(amostra$d001[i]) == TRUE)` the test `== TRUE` is redundant, it basically does nothing.

Comment: Please supply your "amostra" object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

The problem, apparently, was the order.

The code below ran ok:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(amostra)) {
if (is.na(amostra$d001[i]) == TRUE) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- 99
} else if (amostra$d001[i] == 2) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- 0
} else if (amostra$d002[i] == 1) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- vlookup(amostra$d003[i], educd003, result_column = 2, lookup_column = 1)
} else if (amostra$d002[i] == 2 & amostra$d008[i] == 2) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- 2
} else if (amostra$d002[i] == 2 & amostra$d008[i] == 1 & is.na(amostra$d014[i]) == TRUE) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- vlookup(amostra$d009[i], educd0092, result_column = 2, lookup_column = 1)
} else if (amostra$d002[i] == 2 & amostra$d008[i] == 1 & amostra$d014[i] == 1) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- vlookup(amostra$d009[i], educd0091, result_column = 2, lookup_column = 1)
} else if (amostra$d002[i] == 2 & amostra$d008[i] == 1 & amostra$d014[i] == 2) {
  amostra$escol[i] <- vlookup(amostra$d009[i], educd0092, result_column = 2, lookup_column = 1)
} else {
  amostra$escol[i] <- NA
}
}
```

Thank you very much anyway!